# Is vector<int[3]> a; right in C++?

Tags: c++

Is `vector<int[3]> a;` valid C++ ?

Can this cause problems?

Comment: Try it before asking!

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes , it's fine, but you may prefer `std::vector<std::array<int,3>>` for various reasons.

Answer (score -1):

I tried just now...

It can't be compiled successfully on VS.

But if I only code `vector<int[3]> a;`, and don't use this vector, it can be compiled successfully.

Comment: That's exceedingly inaccurate. It's about *how* you use the vector. Some operations cannot be supported for a type like `int[3]`.